# How to detect when language changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate to provide dynamic language support for my app. I am also using a calendar component (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) which doesn't play that well with angular (jQuery roots). To be able to translate it at run time I need to detect when language changes.

Basically I need to know when `$translate.use()` has been called and the language has been changed.

Is there a way to detect when the language changes so that I can trigger the translations for the calendar component?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        // Language has changed
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer :

```
$scope.$watch("$parent.currentLanguage", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // Do whatever you want
});
```